# sacct: How could I convert {CPUTimeRAW and CPUTime} into real time as seconds?

Tags: slurm

My goal is to charge users based on the time(in seconds) they allocated the CPU. What is best parameter to measure it?

The way I run:

**Example 1:**

```
sbatch  -N1 run.sh
Submitted batch job 20
scontrol update jobid=20 TimeLimit=0-00:01
```

---

```
sacct -o totalcpu,cputime,cputimeraw,Elapsed,SystemCPU,time -j 20
  TotalCPU    CPUTime CPUTimeRAW    Elapsed  SystemCPU  Timelimit
---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
  00:00:00   00:11:52        712   00:01:29              00:01:00
  00:00:00   00:11:52        712   00:01:29
```

I had put a time limit as 1 minute, but it seems like it exceeds the time limit for 29 seconds. Is it normal?

**Example 2:**

```
sbatch  -N1 run.sh
Submitted batch job 21
scontrol update jobid=21 TimeLimit=0-00:02
```

---

```
sacct -o totalcpu,cputime,cputimeraw,Elapsed,SystemCPU,time -j 21
TotalCPU    CPUTime CPUTimeRAW    Elapsed  SystemCPU  Timelimit
---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
00:00:00   00:18:56       1136   00:02:22              00:02:00
```

I had put a time limit as 2 minute, but it seems like it exceeds the time limit for 22 seconds. Is it normal?

How could I convert {`CPUTimeRAW` and `CPUTime`} into `real time` as seconds? Based on the examples I have shown, I wasn't able to find the relationship between them.

> CPUTimeRaw = Units are  cpu-seconds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The small overrun of the time limit is normal, this is determined by the `KillWait` flag in `slurm.conf`:

> The interval, in seconds, given to a job's processes between the
>   SIGTERM and SIGKILL signals upon reaching its time limit.  If the job
>   fails to terminate gracefully in the interval specified, it will be
>   forcibly terminated.  The default value is 30 seconds.

For charging users:

`CPUTime = (Elapsed time) x (the number of CPUs allocated)`

so `CPUTime` (or `CPUTimeRaw`, the same usage expressed in seconds) is what they actually used and what they can be charged for.

Comment: In the example I mention, on my server 1 second is equivalent to 8 CPUTimeRAW. So I guess number of CPU allocated is 8. So 02:22 * 8 = (CPUTime=00:18:56) which is correct. I was running on 1 core so I guess each core allocates 8 CPU. @ciaron

Comment: If you've set up a node with 8 cores, then running with `-N1` will get you a full node, i.e. an allocation of all 8 cores, correct.